# how to set hyperlinks in non-theorem environment and customise the labelling of Cases 1,2, 3?

Tags: hyperref

(1) Is this the right way to label and reference non-theorem environment?

(2) Can we make the sentence appear as "Cases 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3", i.e., it adds on to the theorem numbering?

(3) Alternatively, is there a way we can customise it to "Cases 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3"(or any desired numbering) by inputting manually?

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} 
\usepackage{esvect}% arrow above letter
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead]{geometry} %margin of 1 inch
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% for hyperlinks

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{ppn}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{con}[thm]{Conjecture}

\begin{document}
\section{FiRsT section}
\section{SeCoNd section}
In this section, we shall prove Theorem \ref{thm1}. In the proof, we split into Cases \ref{case2.1.1}, \ref{case2.1.2}, and \ref{case2.1.3}. %Can we make the sentence appear as "Cases 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3", i.e., it adds on to the theorem numbering? Alternatively, is there a way we can customise it to "Cases 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3"(or any desired numbering) by inputting manually?
\begin{thm}
For any integers $m,n$, $\max\{m,n\}+\min\{m,n\}=m+n$
\\\noindent\textit{Proof}:
\\Case 1. $m< n$. \label{case2.1.1}
\noindent\par Then, $\ldots$
\\
\\Case 2. $m>n$.\label{case2.1.2}
\noindent\par Then, $\ldots$
\\
\\Case 3. $m=n$.\label{case2.1.3}
\noindent\par Then, $\ldots$
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of what current code compiles as]

Comment: Hi there! Before we try to help, perhaps it could be good to clarify what you'd like. Are you trying to create an environment that does what you have above _automatically_, so that you don't have to type "Case 1", "Case 2", etc.? What would you like the labels to do? Unfortunately, I can't run your code  because you have an `\end{thm}` without a `\begin{thm}`. You may find it useful to try making a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/91603), where you include only the code needed for us to understand your issue, so that we can give you more helpful answers.

Comment: Added in ```\begin{thm}```. I want the sentence to appear as " Cases 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3" instead of "Cases 2.1, 2.1, 2.1" as shown in picture. I thought the above is a minimal working example; not sure how else to simplify it.